# Entity Framework Multiple Database Project Structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, project-management

I would like to know what is the advisable approach on creating a project with multiple database using entity framework.

My current solution projects looks like this.

```
SystemName.Data // Points to Database1
SystemName.Core // Points to Database1
SystemName.Database2.Data
SystemName.Database2.Core
SystemName.Database3.Data
SystemName.Database3.Core
SystemName.Business
SystemName.UI
```

Should I put the all the Data and Core assembly in one project?
Should I also create different business projects for each database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In EntityFramework 6 (EF6), you can use multiple contexts on the same database](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations). In EF5, a single user model (DbContext) is managed by only one database instance.

So, the multiple DbContexts can be in different projects, and use the same database instance in **EF6**.

### Update

The databases used by the `DbContext` could be decided by app.config (or web.config). So, I prefer to put my sub-classes of DbContext into different projects according to their purposes. If the database maximum size is considered, like 10GB per database, then put one DbContext to one database might be a good choice. **But in EF6, the DbContext could be considered as a plugin.** If the application needs an extension to gain more abilities, then an extra DbContext will create necessary database for the extension. Some day the extension is not useful, and it needs to be uninstalled, then some tables in the same database will be dropped.

Comment: by the way i'm using entity framework 6 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I updated my answer. I use EF6 in VS 2012. I like EF6.